# How to use withFetch() with no standalone app?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular17

I migrated to angular 17.1. When I ran the app, I noticed error information about using fetch with httpClient for SSR.

```
NG02801: Angular detected that `HttpClient` is not configured to use `fetch` APIs. It's strongly recommended to enable `fetch` for applications that use Server-Side Rendering for better performance and compatibility. To enable `fetch`, add the `withFetch()` to the `provideHttpClient()` call at the root of the application.
```

Application is not bootstrap by standalone component but I found only tutorials for that kind of apps. I put `provideHttpClient(withFetch()),` to `app.server.module.ts` and error disappeared.

Im not sure if it is a correct solution for application bootstraped by AppModule. Do you have better options?

Comment: use get() to fetch data 
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-get-example-using-httpclient/

Comment: Hi, where "withFetch()" come from ? It's not declared in the sample...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [`HttpClientModule` source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/17.1.3/packages/common/http/src/module.ts#L83-L100) it's basically just a wrapper.

If you remove `HttpClientModule` and instead add this to providers it should be fine.

```
provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi(), withFetch()),
```

I'm not sure, but I assume your solution is fine as well.